# Low Level API for Firefox WebExtension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to use `nsInterface` or other low level code in Firefox WebExtensions like Add-on SDK allows by:

```
require("chrome");
```

If so, how can I get the reference for the low level API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently this is not possible. There are plans to allow something similar, dubbed [native.js](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1199718), in a more compartmentalized manner in the future, but it's not yet implemented.